# data.table not accepting 'by' and 'format' (for date) at the same time

Tags: r, data.table

I'm using `data.table` to find the mean date of a "session", but I'm having trouble trying to format it the way I want, and I'm confused as to what the problem is:

```
library( data.table )
data <- data.table( session = c( 1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3 ),
                    date = as.Date( c( "2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03", "2016-01-03",
                                       "2016-04-30", "2016-04-30", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03", "2016-05-03",
                                       "2016-08-28", "2016-08-28", "2016-08-28", "2016-08-28" ) )
)
```

What I want is to give each session a label, based on when that session was. I've decided to label each session as the month during which the session occurred (formatted as "%b-%Y"), but since the sessions sometimes cross over 2 months, I want to do this by taking the mean date of that session, and using that to decide on the label.

I can find the mean date of each session, using the `by` parameter:

```
output <- copy( data )[ , Month := mean( date ), by = session ]
```

I can also reformat a mean date the way I want within `data.table`:

```
output <- copy( data )[ , Month := format( mean( date ), "%b-%Y" ) ]
```

But I can't do both:

```
output <- copy( data )[ , Month := format( mean( date ), "%b-%Y" ), by = session ]
```

The above returns an error:

```
Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  : 
invalid 'trim' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In mean(date) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

What am I doing wrong here? The code looks right to me, and each part works fine, so why isn't this working?

Note I can do what I need in two steps (below), and it works OK, but I'm interested to know what it is I'm missing. Something is wrong in the above code, I just can't see what it is :

```
output <- copy( data )[ , Month := mean( date ), by = session 
                        ][ , Month := format( Month, "%b-%Y" ) ]
```

Comment: `x <- copy(DT)[, z := f()]` is hardly ever a useful way to go.

Comment: @Frank do you mean the `copy` part? I know, I'm only using that for the example since if I don't, the first line of code affects the next one. Running `output <- data[ , Month := mean( date ), by = session ]` adds a new column to `data` such that it changes the behaviour of the next line... I don't think it should be that way, but it does seem to be.

Comment: Report this to the bug tracker on Github.

Comment: OK @Roland, I will. I assume you're saying it's a problem with `data.table`, as opposed to `as.Date` or `mean`?

Comment: Yes, this is possibly a problem with data.table's optimizations. You should first test with data.table's development version and if you can reproduce the bug there, you should report it.

Comment: OK, I will, thanks Roland. I've tried a fresh install from GitHub (v1.9.7), and still the same issue.

Comment: Not only the `copy`, but also the `x <-`. Data.table modifies the object in place deliberately; this is the whole point of `:=` and why you see `data` getting a new column even though you imagine you are simply assigning the result with `output <-`. I'd recommend reading the vignettes to get used to how the package works: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you use `mean.Date` instead of `mean`:

```
output <- copy( data )[ , Month := format( mean.Date( date ), format="%b-%Y" ), by = session ]
```

That way it utilizes `format.Date`

Comment: Thanks! That's a good solution. Do you know why `mean` didn't work in this case? `class(mean(data[,date]))` returns "Date", the same as when using `mean.Date`, so shouldn't `format` be acting on the same class either way?

Comment: PS: I'm happy to accept this answer, since it does provide a solution, but I'd really like to understand the problem first, if anyone can explain it.